# Make links open "pop up" windows with different content

Tags: html, css, popup, unique

I have a table in my HTML code and I put a class in the `<li>` tag as shown below :

```
<li class="modal-trigger"><img src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk/images/movies/21grams.jpg">21 Grams</li>
<li class="modal-trigger"><img src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk/images/movies/amoresperros.jpg">Amores Perros</li>
<li class="modal-trigger"><img src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk/images/movies/babamveoglum.jpg">Babam Ve Oglum</li>
```

When somebody clicks the link, a pop up should show up. I want to make the pop up content unique. If somebody clicks the first one, there should be a pop up with info about the 21grams movie. If somebody clicks the second, for the amoresperros etc :

```
<div id="ModalContentWrap" class="modal-wrap">
  <div class="modal-content mix">
    <section id="stigma-box">
      <header>
        <h1>21 Grams</h1>
        <span class="avatar"><img src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk/images/movies/21grams.jpg" alt="" /></span>
        <h3><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0315733/" target="blank">A freak accident brings together a critically ill mathematician, a grieving mother, and a born-again ex-con.</a></h3> 
      </header>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ModalContentWrap" class="modal-wrap">
  <div class="modal-content mix">
    <section id="stigma-box">
      <header>
        <h1>Amores Perros</h1>
        <span class="avatar"><img src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk/images/movies/amoresperros.jpg" alt="" /></span>
        <h3><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245712/" target="blank">A freak accident brings together a critically ill mathematician, a grieving mother, and a born-again ex-con.</a></h3> 
      </header>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="ModalContentWrap" class="modal-wrap">
  <div class="modal-content mix">
    <section id="stigma-box">
      <header>
        <h1>Father and Son</h1>
        <span class="avatar"><img src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk/images/movies/babamveoglum.jpg" alt="" /></span>
        <h3><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0476735/" target="blank">Sadik is one of the rebellious youth who has been politically active as a university student and became a left-wing journalist in the 70's, despite his father's expectations of him becoming...</a></h3> 
      </header>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this code above, no matter what I click, I am getting a pop up with info for the first movie only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that all your modal's ID's are the same and so you need to change them to be unique. You need to set each trigger to be unique too.

For example(This is just an example of the way to use a modal not usable code):

```
<a href="#test1" data-toggle="modal">Click me for test1 id!</a>
<div id="test1" data-type="modal">
    Some content here...
</div>
```

I suggest you take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp if you are using Bootstrap...

Comment: How can I dynamically change that: id="ModalContentWrap". It has to be id="ModalContentWrap_1" and id="ModalContentWrap_2" etc for every box. But that will make the css file larger.

Comment: That is correct. That is why you are supposed to use a template modal and then load the content using Ajax!

Comment: Any way to do this? Any use case on stackoverflow maybe? I have never used AJAX before.